# How to read file in OEM encoding if PowerShell doesn't provide it?

Tags: powershell, encoding

When used with .Net Framework 2.0 it looks like the OEM encoding isn't available in PowerShell.

```
PS1> Get-Content $FilePath -Encoding OEM
```

> Cannot bind parameter 'Encoding'. Cannot convert value "OEM" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Unknown, String, Unicode, Byte, BigEndianUnicode, UTF8, UTF7, Ascii".

However I have files in this encoding that I'd like to read in a string, how to do it?

Comment: "OEM" is not *an* encoding, but a subset of all encodings. With one assigned to each locale. Therefore changing locale will change its effects. The subset of encodings PowerShell's FileSystem encoder supports is defined by the [`FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.powershell.commands.filesystemcmdletproviderencoding(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration. I note this includes `Oem`: maybe case is important (or PowerShell version).

Comment: Thanks; couldn't find anything clear in MSDN about it. Is it really the same thing as the "current culture oem code page"?

Comment: I *assume* so, without disassembling the filesystem provider (significantly non-trivial) one can only test... Also note that the set of encodings listed by `get-help get-content -param encoding` is smaller than in the enumeration.

Comment: It's implied by the question, but to make it explicit: PowerShell **v3** now DOES support the `Oem` encoding value directly; the - excellent - workaround below is only needed in **v2**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read in a binary array and decode it :

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Host.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
$text = $enc.GetString($bytes)
```